# What is the best way to store potatoes that were already cut?

Tags: potatoes, storage

And prevent them from becoming darker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a vacuum sealer for storing all sorts of food. If that is not an alternative, you can put them in the fridge in a moist plastic bag. Or you can have them in a bowl of water a day or so.